# Import a JSON file that uses arrays

Tags: plugin-feedme, array, import

I'm working with a live stock API and want to import the products on a daily basis (using a cron job probably). At this moment I've setup a Feed Me feed as entries. This works for all products where the data is presented one by one. But the data does also have a part with an array and inside that array also columns, arrays like this:

```
{
   "supplier_data_columns": ["value1", "value2", "value3" {
    "properties": {
      "203": "width_package",
      "205": "height_package",
      "206": "length_package"
    }
  }]
}
```

This is then used in the article descriptions:

```
"supplier_data": [
      ["F.15852", "Scott", "2557" {
      "203": "50",
      "205": "40",
      "206": "100"
      }]
```

How do I address this? Is this even possible with Feed Me? Do I need to import the whole array at once as "supplier data" and then extract the right columns in the entry? Or is a module needed here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't fully understand you...
But, I think what you need is to make your own module and hook the event from FeedMe.

```
    use craft\feedme\services\Process;
    use craft\feedme\events\FeedProcessEvent;
    use craft\feedme\events\FeedDataEvent;
    use craft\feedme\services\DataTypes;
    use craft\elements\Entry;

Event::on(DataTypes::class, DataTypes::EVENT_AFTER_PARSE_FEED, static function (FeedDataEvent $event): void {
   if (!$event->response['success']) {
      return;
   }

   $data = $event->response['data'];
   // .. Deal with data here, e.g. parse correctly JSON or change it
}
```

Or probably something like that

```
Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_STEP_AFTER_ELEMENT_SAVE, function (FeedProcessEvent $event) {
    $myEntry = $event->element;
    // ... Change your JSON structure or do what you want after element saved
}
```

Comment: Okay so the right thing to do would be to change the JSON data so that it will be workable for Feed Me. I'll look into it.

Comment: I've had success with pasting JSON data into a string variable into Chrome's console, then using JavaScript to manipulate the data to turn it into a format that's easier to use with Feed Me. Lots of `.map()` to get the data into more consistent formats! Once it's right, you can copy it out from the console and paste into a JSON file to use with Feed Me.